# Storing Data To Config File

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having some problems trying to store data into a config file in `Codeigniter`

**The Problem**

The session data grows too big and seems to exceed the 4kb which is the cookie max size. As a result for example flashdata stops working.

**Why It Happens**

It seems that config variables are added 4 times into the session inside of following objects:

- `CI_Hooks` Object (should be turned off)
- `CI_Utf8` Object
- `MY_Router` Object (used for replacing `'_'` with `'-'` in URL)
- `CI_URI` Object

Interestingly the hooks object is present even if the functionality is turned off in the config file:  `$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;`

**Questions**

1 - how do you store config data without it being multiplied in the session?
2 - also, why does the hooks object seem to be enabled when it has been disabled in the config?

**Other Details**

- CI_VERSION  2.1.3
- Session library is autoloaded
- Sessions are stored into db
- Session cookie is encrypted
- Config files are loaded in the pages where they are used, mainly inside constructors
- The config data is not huge and would fit very well to 4kb if it wasn't multiplied

`Session data ( print_r($this->session) ) :
[hooks] => CI_Hooks Object ( [enabled] => [hooks] => Array ( ) [in_progress] => ) [config] => CI_Config Object ( [config] => Array...`

Thanks in advance for your help, it would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with CI sessions (which are just really cookies) I would suggest using a different session library.

[This one uses native PHP sessions](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session), so you don't get the problems with the 4kb limit, or if you really want to keep with CI sessions then use the database function to store the values.